# How do I style the place holder and background of an input form using vue js and element-plus

Tags: css, vuejs3, element-plus

I'm trying to change the font-style, font-size, font-weight and some others for the the placeholder and the internal part of an input form in vue3 and element plus.

i've tried styling it separately in the style section but it doesn't sem to work unless i use inline styling.

so far ive been only able to style the outer part but i can't seem to figure out hoe to do that of the inner part of the input form.

I've tried using inspect on the browser but still no improvement.

i know most of element-plus have their styling already but i can't seem to figure out how to customize them the way i want.

I'm still new to using vue3 and element-plus

```
<el-input v-model="input"  
           style="width: 614px;
            height: 82px;
            border: 1px solid rgba(168, 192, 39, 1);
            border-radius: 10px;
            margin-left: 653px;
            margin-top: 28px;
             " placeholder="Enter your email address" />
```

this is the code i wrote in the  tag

```
.el-input__inner{
    width: 375px;
    height: 39px;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 400px;
    line-height: 38.73px;
    margin: 21px 200px 22px 39px;
}

.el-input__wrapper{
    align-items: center;
    padding: none !important;
    border-radius: 10px;

}
```

I used the class names which were given when i inspected the code on the web browser

Comment: Is the `<style>` tag [scoped](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#scoped-css)?

Comment: @yoduh yes the style is scoped. initially it wasn't but different elements started using the style of others so i had to make it scoped in order to prevent that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scoped styles can at most only affect the root element of child components.  For a scoped style to affect the inner elements of a child component, you must use the [`:deep()`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#deep-selectors) selector.

```css
<style scoped>
.el-input :deep(.el-input__inner){
    width: 375px;
    height: 39px;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 400px;
    line-height: 38.73px;
    margin: 21px 200px 22px 39px;
}

.el-input :deep(.el-input__wrapper){
    align-items: center;
    padding: none !important;
    border-radius: 10px;

}
</style>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. for the most part the the style for the inner element worked but I still can't set the background color inside the input form. i don't know if it can be done or not, but I've tried and it didn't work.

Comment: Pretty much any style can be overridden if you know what to target.  "I've tried and it didn't work" doesn't help others debug the problem with you.  Always show what code you tried.

Comment: I poked around in the DOM of a page with el-input, modifying the styles manually.  Maybe you want to try adding the background color to the `.el-input__wrapper` style

Comment: is there a way I can show you what Im working on that way you could see what im trying to say

Comment: You could edit your question to add more code.  Or include a screenshot if it's a visual thing you need to show.  Maybe easiest would actually be to use the Element Plus playground, which all code examples in the documentation include links to.  Here is a playground showing a colored el-input background: [link](https://shorturl.at/KRT34)

Answer (score 0):

After going through the answer @yoduh provided I was finally able to get the desired look.

So for the background color to be set:

```css
.el-input :deep(.el-input__wrapper){
    padding: none !important;
    background-color: rgba(246, 249, 233, 1);
}
```

and to change the styling of the placeholder:

```css
.el-input :deep(.el-input__inner){
    height: 39px;
    width: 375px;
    
    padding: none !important;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 400px;
    line-height: 38.73px;
    opacity: 80%;
    color: rgba(148, 148, 148, 0.55);
    margin: 21px  22px 39px;
    text-align: center;
}
```